# Set / Get value of dictionary via list of keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I would like to get and set values in a dictionary using a list of keys.

I would like to be able to use a list of keys like this

`lis = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]`

to effectively do something like this

`dict["key1"]["key2"]["key3"] = "value"`

or this

`value = dict["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]`